# Is it better to make custom registration with editing Django UserCreationForm class or make it on a new table and class?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I wanted to make a Django authentication but I was confused about wichone is better?
is it is better to edit the `venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py` file and make my custom form and edit DB on `venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py` or it's better to make my authentication system with model and views and forms on my application?

Comment: None. you can inherit the classes from both and make changes.

Comment: it's true. but I want to know which way is better. edit django initial files or start a new app and make the things that I need.

Comment: my point is 1. why would you want to edit a django file when you can add more functionality in it. 
2. "starting a new app and make the things that you want" --> django already have authentication system. unless you have something very different.

Comment: is there any difference between "inherit Django authentication in my app", "edit Django initial authentication files" or "make my own authentication". difference like (speed, security and ...)

Comment: [ 1 ] "make my authentication" is something that you know. 

[ 2 ] "edit Django initial files": NO( that's not Django is for)


[ 3 ]" Inherit Django functionalities in your app ": YES because that's what people are doing and that's why probably you are using Django. else if you are worry about speed. it would be good enough to not let you change your authentication.


I don't have any index for speed.

Comment: The speed is not my concern, I just want to know if there's any difference in the way that I make my authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add django's files. you can inherit there properties.
for example let's say you want to use User model of Django. you can do that in your models.py like following.  here you ll get all the fields of Abstract User like first_name, email, passwords etc but you can add your own fields such as technoking in below example

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
import uuid

class User(AbstractUser):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    technoking = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: it's good but i want an explanation about which way is better